# Why is my TextField so small on the screen when targeting Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, haxe, openfl

Read that the default size should be 12px. Is this something about DPI? How to solve?

[image]

**EDIT**
Thank you folks, but this doesn't seams to be something related to the font size. It looks like its something about handling DPI because it happens with simple `Sprite`s too and weirdly the colors on Android seams to use an inversed RGB sequence

[image]

The `Main.hx`:

```
package;

import openfl.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import openfl.display.Sprite;
import openfl.display.StageAlign;
import openfl.display.StageScaleMode;
import openfl.events.Event;
import openfl.system.Capabilities;
import openfl.text.TextField;
import ru.stablex.ui.UIBuilder;

class Main extends Sprite
{   
    private var size: Float = 100;

    private var r: Sprite;
    private var g: Sprite;
    private var b: Sprite;

    public function new()
    {
        super();        
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function addedToStage(event: Event): Void
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        r = createSquare(this, 0x00FF0000, size);
        g = createSquare(this, 0x0000FF00, size);
        b = createSquare(this, 0x000000FF, size);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resize, false, 0, true);
        resize(null);
    }

    private function resize(event: Event): Void
    {
        r.x = 0;
        r.y = 0;

        g.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (size / 2);
        g.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (size / 2);

        b.x = stage.stageWidth - size;
        b.y = stage.stageHeight - size;
    }

    private function createSquare(parent: DisplayObjectContainer, color: Int, size: Float): Sprite
    {
        var box: Sprite = new Sprite();

        box.graphics.beginFill(color);
        box.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
        box.graphics.endFill();

        parent.addChild(box);

        return box;
    }
}
```

Comment: TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sp` size unit, which always seems the same size on different dpi screens.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
 text.autoSize = "center";
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFieldAutoSize.html

You can size `Sprite` size to 100%.

[Auto size text field with Actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428013/auto-size-text-field-with-actionscript-3) -- This link can help you.